# C++ Null characters in string?

Tags: c++, null-character

I want to read a txt file and convert two cells from each line to floats.

If I first run:

```
someString = someString.substr(1, tempLine.size());
```

And then:

```
std::stof(someString)
```

it only converts the first number in 'someString' to a number. The rest of the string is lost.
When I handled the string in my IDE I noticed that copying it and pasting it inside quotation marks gives me `"\u00005\u00007\u0000.\u00007\u00001\u00007\u00007\u0000"` and not `57.7177`.

If I instead do:

```
std::string someOtherString = "57.7177"

std::stof(someOtherString)
```

I get `57.7177`.

Minimal working example is:

```
int main() {

std::string someString = "\u00005\u00007\u0000.\u00007\u00001\u00007\u00007\u0000";
float someFloat =  std::stof(someString);
return 0;
}
```

Same problem occurs using both UTF-8 and -16 encoding.

What is happening and what should I do differently? Should I remove the null-characters somehow?

Comment: What is the character code of the txt file? Is it UTF-16?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @tadman: Its' UTF16BE.  The `5` and the `7` aren't the values 5 and 7, they're the characters 5 and 7.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh, I misread that as `\u0005` instead of `\0000` and then `5`. I think that's the answer then!

Comment: The trend is to use [UTF-8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) but on some ill-configured operating systems (old Windows computers) it is still not the case. Without any [mre] your question stays unclear

Answer (score 3):

"I want to read a txt file"

What is the encoding of the text file?  "Text" is not a encoding.  What I suspect is happening is that you wrote code that reads in the file as either UTF8 or Windows-1250 encoding, and stored it in a `std::string`.  From the bytes, I can see that the file is actually UTF16BE, and so you need to read into a `std::u16string`.  If your program will *only* ever run on Windows, then you can get by with a `std::wstring`.

You probably have followup questions, but your original question is vague enough that I can't predict what those questions would be.